# Access remote sql server using VB.NET

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I've found a few examples of using vb.net to access an sql database, so far none of them have worked . They all involve using DataReaders. Maybe its the fact that the sql db is not on the same machine as the application.

I was just wondering if anyone had a more comprehensive example of using VB.NET to access a remote sql server.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've received a few helpful comments an replies already. So far my connection string looks like:
"server=sqlblah.myhost.com;uid=myuser;pwd=pass;database=testdb"

Probably also good to mention their is no editing of the tables a this point, just reading.

Comment: There is no specific difference except setting the connectionstring to the appropriate server. Maybe your server is behind firewall or doesn't allow TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: What does your connection string look like and what error are you receiving?

Comment: Have you been able to connect with a tool such as SQL Server Management Studio? (this would help check whether the problem is with your code, or your connectivity)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the SQLClient class.

One convienent way to access a SQL database is to fill a DataSet object with query data with a DataAdapter object.

```
Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM ???"
Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("connection string")
Dim da As New SqlClient.DataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet

da.Fill(ds, "TABLE NAME")
```

You can then access the "TABLE NAME" table in the DataSet object.
The "connection string" is obviously your SQL connection string.
Use the sSQL string to query as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Quick side note - a helpful tool for creating connection strings:-

Open up a text document (notepad, wordpad etc) and save a blank document with the extension ".UDL". 
This will give you a "Data link Properties" mini app.

Open up the app and change the provider in the "Provider" to whichever provider you need (in this case OLE DB Provider for SQL Server).

You then need to build up the connection in the connection tab.
Once you have chosen the criteria (ServerName (the drop down list will show you all visible Servers), Security permissions,Database (this drop down list will be populated based on the server chosen)) you can test your connection (to make sure you have permissions etc).

Click ok to close the App, rename the file to have a ".txt" extension and re-open in a text editor, hey presto, one built up connection string (as below).

`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=YOURDBNAME;Data Source=YOURSERVERNAME`